# CNAME Record with any other Resource Record in BIND

Tags: domain-name-system, bind, dns-zone

As per best of my understanding, CNAME can't exist with any other RR in DNS Server.
I am using BIND 9.9.5.

Now when i am adding CNAME record with a domain which already has NS Records, i am not getting any warning or error while checking zone with named-checkzone utility.

Also i restarted my named process and it doesn't give me any warning for the same while restarting the process.

I am wondering what's wrong. Do DNS bind program not suppose to give warning for CNAME stuff ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I find this unlikely.

```
$ORIGIN example.com.
sub    IN NS ns1.example.net.
sub    IN CNAME example.net.

# named-checkzone example.com test.zone
dns_master_load: test.zone:20: sub.example.com: CNAME and other data
```

A quick Google of `CNAME and other data` shows that this error message has been around [as far back as 9.2.4](http://www.umich.edu/~umce/linux/mail-archive/msg00141.html), so I don't feel compelled to look further.

I suggest checking your zone file for syntax that is changing the FQDN of the record to something unexpected (typo, trailing dot, `$ORIGIN` statement, etc.). Even if you cannot spot a typo, it is highly recommended that you edit your original question to show the contents of the zone file. This will allow others to determine what is happening.

Comment: +1, especially for the recommendation to  **include the unredacted contents of the zonefile**.  DNS questions in particular are often hard to answer without full disclosure.

Comment: Thanks....Issue was actually of $ORIGIN statement which has caused repetition of zone name.

Answer (score 0):

Try [named-checkzone](http://ftp.isc.org/www/bind/arm95/man.named-checkzone.html).

```
named-checkzone <zonename> /var/named/<filename>
```

http://bencane.com/2011/10/06/bind-checking-a-zone-record-for-errors/

Comment: I had done that... But it is not giving any warning or error for CNAME co-existence with NS Record.